# bar chart grouped by the sex column

Tags: python, pandas, grouped-bar-chart

I have a data frame that looks something like this and I want am trying to make two grouped bar charts where one is grouped by sex and it shows the counts for the disease for males and females:

| Age | Sex | disease |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | m | 0 |
| 43 | m | 1 |
| 32 | f | 0 |
| 51 | f | 1 |
| 29 | m | 1 |

This is what ive tried but it shows every datapoint instead of the total counts.

`heart_failure_df.set_index(['Sex']).plot(y='disease', kind="bar")`

This is ideally what i want:

[image]

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html) example of Matplotlib?

Comment: @EmilViesná Yeah this ended up working. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Chart:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = {'Age': [23, 43, 32, 51, 29], 
     'Sex': ['m', 'm', 'f', 'f', 'm'],
     'disease': [0, 1, 0, 1, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(
    df,
    index="Sex",
    columns="disease",
    values="disease",
    aggfunc='count')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df_pivot.plot(kind="bar", ax=ax)
ax.legend(["Normal", "Heart Disease"]);
ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=0)
ax.set_ylabel("count")
```

- Pivot puts the dataframe in the correct format to be plotted as grouped bar chart by `pd.plot()` and counts the occurrences of disease in one step.
- The legend needs to be set manually since in your data `disease` is '0', '1'.

Answer (score 0):

First formulate your data

```
s = df.groupby('Sex')['Disease'].count()
```

After that slice it a little bit

Only males data `s['M']`

Only females data `s['F']`

This shall return the series with the wanted y axis and x axis. After that just  a simple plot shall do your trick

Just take a look at the documentation (https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html)